# Adding web service layer to Leaflet map?

Tags: leaflet, wms, esri-leaflet

I am trying to add layer 12 (warnings) in this services directory to a Leaflet map:
https://igems.doi.gov/arcgis/rest/services/igems_haz/MapServer

I have been able to add the layer using WMS and ESRI's vector feature layer format, but neither works for me.  WMS performs quickly, but I haven't been able to get popup info windows that are useful.  With ESRI feature layer, it is the opposite: the info windows work great, but the large vector layer slows everything down.

At the top of services directory page it says "JSON | SOAP | WMS".  Do JSON and SOAP refer to different formats besides WMS and ESRI's Feature Layer format that I can use in Leaflet?

Most of my experience is in the desktop GIS, so I am still not 100% on the different formats and specifications for webGIS.

Comment: Rather than investigating yet more options why don't you investigate why either WMS or "ESRI feature layer format" does not meet your requirements?  I suspect either should be able to.

Comment: The popups don't work for WMS because WMS uses XML instead of JSON which is more amenable to JavaScript libraries like Leaflet.  I've had a developer explain to me how it can be done, but it was over my head.

ESRI feature layer format (I am not exactly what it is but I just know it works with ESRI Leaflet) doesn't work good because it transmits the data in a vector format.  With the NWS Warnings layer, we're talking about thousands of vertices and it is simply too much data to download quickly plus it freezes on mobile devices.

Comment: Please use the [edit] button beneath your question to revise it with any requested clarifications. By "ESRI feature layer format" it sounds like you mean an ArcGIS Server Feature Service.  Why don't you try an ArcGIS Server Map Service (equivalent of WMS) instead?

Comment: To be honest, I've tried to figure out exactly format this is, but I have not find any place that explains it. All I know is that I can add it to my map using L.esri.feature layer, but that it is much slower than WMS and freezes on mobile devices. The documentation for l.esri.featurelayer says it can be used to visualize layers from "ArcGIS Online and published using ArcGIS Server" but doesn't clearly explain the format that it uses to transmit the data.

Comment: I think you need to research/ask some more specific questions.  As it stands I am likely to vote for the current open-ended "What other options do I have?" to be placed On Hold as too broad.

Comment: I've been working on this for a year now. How much longer do I need to research so that I can ask the question in a manner that pleases you?

Comment: You started by saying "I am trying to add layer 12 (warnings) in this services directory to a Leaflet map: https://igems.doi.gov/arcgis/rest/services/igems_haz/MapServer".  If you can include a code snippet to illustrate precisely how you tried to do that and where you got stuck then you will have a much more focussed question.

Comment: I am not getting stuck with the code. I'm having trouble with the performance. I am currently using l.esri.featurelayer to add the layer to the map, but it takes too long to load. You can see for yourself here: http://disastermap.net/WebMapApps/index.html. I had previously used leaflet.wms.js. It loaded quickly, but I could never format the pop-up info windows in a way that was useful. Then it just suddenly stopped working, I think because of an ESRI update. I now need to know options I have to get fast performance and useful pop windows.

Comment: For focussed Q&A I think you'll get further quicker by moving away from "I've tried 3 (?) things that don't work so what are other options?" to here is the code that illustrates one thing that I tried and shows precisely where I got stuck.  Because it's a Leaflet question some JavaScript code is expected in your question.  If the first of three yields no way forward, ask about the second separately, and if necessary the third separately.  Whenever, our users think there is a better way forward you can rest assured that showing effort like this is likely to get them suggesting it.

Comment: I don't know what to tell you other than this is where I am at right now with the project and that is question that I need answered.  But since you've decided that is the wrong question, I guess I won't find my answer here.

Comment: Unfortunately, not all questions are good questions "as-is" for the focussed Q&A format used by Stack Exchange sites but I do think that many of those that our users give up on can actually be re-written into a more answerable form quite easily by re-casting them as "what I want to do, precisely what I tried and precisely where I'm stuck".

Comment: I admit that I don't know enough about this aspect of GIS to ask to the question the right way.

Comment: I'm not sure why you say that the `The popups don't work for WMS because WMS uses XML instead of JSON`, you need to do a `GetFeatureInfo request`, responses can come back in various formats HTML/XML/text/`GeoJSON`...  for example: http://igems.doi.gov/arcgis/services/igems_haz/MapServer/WmsServer?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&REQUEST=GetFeatureInfo&BBOX=53.57492155255879851,-172.07462304179105672,79.9474635399785285,-140.7313401562189199&CRS=EPSG:4326&WIDTH=1135&HEIGHT=955&LAYERS=0&STYLES=&FORMAT=image/jpeg&QUERY_LAYERS=0&INFO_FORMAT=application/geojson&I=471&J=638&FEATURE_COUNT=10

Comment: I don't know JQuery or how to parse a GetFeatureInfo. For a while I used the leaflet.wms.js plugin. However, it was difficult to read, had too much non-useful info that made it harder to use, then it just stopped working all together when Hurricane Hermine was making landfall. Like I said, my training and most of my experience is with desktop GIS. For a year, I've been struggling with this issue in Leaflet. That's not to say I don't have a useful service. During and after every major disaster this year, I've got requests for information and thanks for helping people get to safety.

Comment: It sounds like investigating "The popups don't work for WMS because WMS uses XML instead of JSON" would make a focussed question with a potential answerer already showing interest.

Comment: I have asked that question before, and answer was beyond my ability to implement.  What I would like to know if is if there are other formats for this particular layer besides WMS or ESRI's vector format that will allow me to add the layer in Leaflet?

Answer (score 1):

> At the top of services directory page it says "JSON | SOAP | WMS". Do JSON and SOAP refer to different formats

Not to different formats, but rather to different interface protocols ~ ways to obtain the data through your client/software.

So WMS (Web Map Service), for example, the principle output are map images (as part of the GetMap request), in this service available formats are:

```
<GetMap>
    <Format>image/bmp</Format>
    <Format>image/jpeg</Format>
    <Format>image/tiff</Format>
    <Format>image/png</Format>
    <Format>image/png8</Format>
    <Format>image/png24</Format>
    <Format>image/png32</Format>
    <Format>image/gif</Format>
    <Format>image/svg+xml</Format>
```

So if you're wanting to access the service in Leaflet and want to have multiple layers on top of each other you'll probably want to request an `image/png`* format (as it supports transparency).

And also to obtain data at a give point in the map, through a GetFeatureInfo request then the formats available in this services are:

```
<GetFeatureInfo>
    <Format>application/vnd.esri.wms_raw_xml</Format>
    <Format>application/vnd.esri.wms_featureinfo_xml</Format>
    <Format>application/vnd.ogc.wms_xml</Format>
    <Format>application/geojson</Format>
    <Format>text/xml</Format>
    <Format>text/html</Format>
    <Format>text/plain</Format>
```

So if you want to work with JSON in Leaflet you can request the format to be `application/geojson`, though you might not want to edit/parse the response and instead use the preformatted `text/html` format.

SOAP (Simple Object Access Protocol) is a protocol generally used programmatically, and not necessarily over the web (over HTTP), to access the data.  You probably won't want to use this to provide maps to Leaflet.  Image formats available in this service are:

```
<xs:enumeration value="esriImageNone"/>
<xs:enumeration value="esriImageBMP"/>
<xs:enumeration value="esriImageJPG"/>
<xs:enumeration value="esriImageDIB"/>
<xs:enumeration value="esriImageTIFF"/>
<xs:enumeration value="esriImagePNG"/>
<xs:enumeration value="esriImagePNG24"/>
<xs:enumeration value="esriImageEMF"/>
<xs:enumeration value="esriImagePS"/>
<xs:enumeration value="esriImagePDF"/>
<xs:enumeration value="esriImageAI"/>
<xs:enumeration value="esriImageGIF"/>
<xs:enumeration value="esriImageSVG"/>
<xs:enumeration value="esriImagePNG32"/>
<xs:enumeration value="esriImageJPGPNG"/>
```

JSON (JavaScript Object Notation) refers to an ESRI web API.  Image formats available in this service are:

```
"supportedImageFormatTypes": "PNG32,PNG24,PNG,JPG,DIB,TIFF,EMF,PS,PDF,GIF,SVG,SVGZ,BMP",
```